# Raphael and seamless tiles (images)

Tags: javascript, raphael

I would like to paint several seamless images side by side with Raphael. This works in Chrome but not in firefox. For some reason firefox paint the images with small space between them.

You can see that in the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bxK4b/4/

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0, 200, 200);

var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var size = 10;
var url = "http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/alliedcomputergraphics/alliedcomputergraphics1206/alliedcomputergraphics120600904/14063568-ground-cover-seamless-texture-tile.jpg";

for (x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    for (y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
        rect = paper.image(url, x * size, y * size , size, size);
    }
}
```

Sometimes it is possible to paint the images with no space, but if you try to put them in a set and scale the complete set 2 or 3 times, the space between the images comes appears again.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Adding 0.5 to the x co-ordinate does it for me:

```
rect = paper.image(url, x * size + .5, y * size , size, size);
```

not sure why adding .5 to y is unnecessary but the [concept is from here](http://www.cairographics.org/FAQ/#sharp_lines).

Comment: This seems to be the right way... and it solves that for the example! But unfortunately the example is just a reduced version of my problem... or I thought it would be... In my real-world-situation I have this small space only after scaling 2 or 3 times. In the linked article is mentioned that this could be solved by rounding, but I fear that this is impossible in Raphael... or I just don't know how to do that...